# Python socket doesn't connect even when I tried all numbers in the range of 0-255

Tags: python, sockets, ip

Made a very simple client-server, wanted to check if just by checking 0-255 for the last number in the ip (e.g = '8.8.8.' and then using the numbers 0-255 for the last number). However, when I run it it always pauses on 0 and then it just zooms through numbers 1-255. any idea why?

Server:

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('8.8.8.8', 5000))
server_socket.listen()

conn, addr = server_socket.accept()

msg = conn.recv(1024).decode()

print(msg)
```

Client:

```
import socket
ip = '8.8.8.'
client_socket = socket.socket()
for i in range(0,255):
    ip = ip +str(i)
    print(i)
    try:
        client_socket.connect((ip,5000))
        client_socket.send('yay'.encode())
    except socket.error:
        pass
```

btw, no I did not use the ip address 8.8.8.8 for bind my server socket, just a general example. I'm saying just in case ^^

Comment: im pretty sure you ran into any problem at all because you are suppressing all socket errors with that `except socket.error: pass` if you hadn't suppressed it you would have seen that you're getting one exception for the first iteration and a different exception for the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a fresh socket for each connect:

```
import socket

for i in range(0, 256):
    print(i)
    ip = f'8.8.8.{i}'
    try:
        client_socket = socket.socket()
        client_socket.connect((ip, 5000))
        client_socket.sendall('yay'.encode())
    except socket.error:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... Can I know why exactly do I know to open a new socket every new time? it is because the previous socket objects errors out or that the connect method finalizes the socket object to a determined ip address?

Comment: Yes, sockets can't be reused once they've tried to connect.